# Jenkins Scan Multibranch Pipeline stopped detecting develop branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, multibranch-pipeline

I am using an organization folder in Jenkins to discover all repositories that contain a Jenkinsfile.

It had been working fine until recently. At some point, the develop branch of one of the repositories was removed. That branch does exist and contains a valid Jenkinsfile.

When I rescan the project the log shows how it examines the branch but says nothing about finding or not finding the Jenkinsfile:

```
Looking up myorg/myrepo for branches
Checking branch develop from myorg/myrepo
Checking branch master from myorg/myrepo
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
...
```

What could be the problem here? Any advice about how to troubleshoot this?

I've tried the usual solutions: delete the branch, create new ones that are detected without any problem, recreate the develop branch...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is sure that Jenkinsfile has no errors, and still looking for a solution to this, following would be good place to start with.

Ensure the below options are enabled:
In SCM configuration > Branch Sources > Discover branches
In SCM configuration > Branch Sources > Filter by name (with wildcards) > Include > <branch_name>

Comment: This was helpful for me.

I was copying a configuration from a working project to a new project and accidentally selected "Filter by name (with wildcards)" instead of "Filter by name (with regular expression)", and although everything looked right, all of my branches were being filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious check, but still, worth a check :

- Typo in Jenkinsfile name in dev branch

  - Try a pull request from master *(that seems to works)* to dev branch
- Scan filter in Folder setup updated ?
- JenkinsFile syntax could be wrong ? *(not sure if it can impact, but you might have a look if something changed in dev lately)*
- dev branch visibility constrain ?

Hope this helps
Regards